# Clients losing stateless ipv6 addresses

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6

I'm having problems with Linux VM's at a certain VPS hoster. Periodically the hosts lose their ipv6 address. They go to 'deprecated' and then disappear completely. On the client side I have checked the following:

```
# sysctl -a |grep tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 0

# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 1

# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Ip6tables on the hosts has rules to allow icmp6 packets in and out. The hosts are Debian 7. Ifdown/ifup does not restore the IP, but a reboot does. Then the problem will reoccur hours or days later. The provider claims that the problem must be with my configuration, but I don't know what. All suggestions welcome.

UPDATE: provider is tilaa.com.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `ip6tables` drops router advertisements (ICMPv6 type 9).

You need to allow **all** ICMPv6 packet types in `ip6tables`.

Comment: How did you see his firewall rules? I don't see them in the question.

Comment: See my original question. All icmp6 traffic is allowed in and out.